# Forgotten rebase interactive - git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I ran some times ago some `git rebase -i` command. But I completely forgot it. Now I want to change new commits order. So I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, and I get normally

```
It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.
```

But I don't even remember what this rebase was all about. How can I find what was the precise purpose of that `rebase`.

Comment: To help with the forgetting part, you can include the the git status in your command prompt which will tell you if you're in the middle of an interactive rebase among other things. Here's a link with the basics http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/2010/05/22/git-ps1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to `your_app/.git/rebase-merge` and find some related informations.

Comment: Where do I find the file with the commits that I edit?

Answer (score 12):

It seems like you unexpectedly quit from `rebase` and for this you get this error in terminal.

To solve this, you need to quit from current rebase and create a new one.

```
git rebase --quit
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to read `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` which contains the next `rebase --interactive` commands that will be run, however, it's much easier to just abort the rebase: `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an old forgotten rebase and you already moved on with things, then you probably don't care anymore (except for learning purposes) and you could just abort the old rebase with

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: that's what I did but I lost all the commits I made in that branch, please help !

Comment: You never lose commits until they are gc'ed which by default would only happen after 30 days. Just youse `git reflog` to look for your "lost" commits and then check them out.